# How to copy a columnfamily from one cassandra cluster to another?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

**How to copy a columnfamily from one cassandra cluster to another?**

**Scenario:**

1. I have only host's IP(for both source and target clusters), port, key_space name and column_family name.
2. I already created metadata in target cluster(only data needs to be copy).
3. **Most preferentially**,I want this to be done in single/multiple spark jobs(creating DataFrame intermediately and then saving it) using spark-cassandra connector JAVA API.
4. **Moderate preferentially**, using cassandra-java driver from datastax.
5. **Least preferentially**, using cassandra-jdbc driver and spark-cassandra connector JAVA API.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

After putting lot of efforts we found solution for this. This solution is very simple and crazy. We can very well do this using spark, let see we did.

**What we were doing(which didn't worked):**

```
// Reading from first cassandra cluster

dataframe = cassandraSQLContext.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options("otherOptionsMap").option("spark.cassandra.connection.host","firstClusterIP").load();

// Writing to second cassandra cluster

dataframe.write.mode("saveMode").options("otherOptionsMap").option("spark.cassandra.connection.host","secondClusterIP").save();
```

**What worked fine:**

```
// Reading from first cassandra cluster

dataframe = cassandraSQLContext.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options("otherOptionsMap").option("spark_cassandra_connection_host","firstClusterIP").load();

// Writing to second cassandra cluster

dataframe.write.mode("saveMode").options("otherOptionsMap")option("spark_cassandra_connection_host","secondClusterIP").save();
```

Yes, thats right you just have to change **period(`.`)** **to underscore( `_` )** for property in spark-cassandra host property. I don't know if this is a bug in spark-cassandra connector.

Comment: FYI, the actual line that allows this transformation is https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/9ee7e7acb2befb81e791e7178ea0da7b4ab52133/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra/DefaultSource.scala#L138

Comment: @MartinTapp Thanks for link!

Comment: From Spark 1.6, no need of (.) to (_) conversion anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Take a snapshot on your existing cluster and use the bulk-loader on the target cluster, no need for Spark (although you could do it that way).

Here are [the docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html) on the procedure, but I'll provide a high level overview of what you need to do.

1. Take a snapshot on the existing cluster
2. Send (`scp`) the snapshot to a node on the new cluster
3. Create a clone of the schema (you said you've already done this)
4. Use the bulk-loader to stream sstables from the snapshot into the new cluster.

Comment: Hi.. I have some questions 1. Does all the steps you mentioned can be perform using cassandra-java driver(or java)? 2. As you have mentioned, how I can achieve it using spark? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector), it offers support for connecting multiple clusters by default. The relevant code snippet is below:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext


def twoClusterExample ( sc: SparkContext) = {
  val connectorToClusterOne = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1"))
  val connectorToClusterTwo = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.2"))

  val rddFromClusterOne = {
    // Sets connectorToClusterOne as default connection for everything in this code block
    implicit val c = connectorToClusterOne
    sc.cassandraTable("ks","tab")
  }

  {
    //Sets connectorToClusterTwo as the default connection for everything in this code block
    implicit val c = connectorToClusterTwo
    rddFromClusterOne.saveToCassandra("ks","tab")
  }

}
```

[Here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#example-of-reading-from-one-cluster-and-writing-to-another) is the relevant documentation and the example code snippet.

Comment: hey,can you help me with this,I have done everything the same way but when I try to see the data in other table(copied data) it is empty,but my task got completed.

Answer (score 0):

Java example

This will work

```
private static String sourceKeyspace = null;
private static String targetKeyspace = null;
private static String sourceHost = null;
private static String targetHost = null;
private static String sourceUsername = null;
private static String targetUsername = null;
private static String sourcePassword = null;
private static String targetPassword = null;
private static String sourceColumnFamily = null;
private static String targetColumnFamily = null;
private static String[] sourceColumns = null;
// Set all above values according to your requirements

private static JavaSparkContext sc;
SparkConf sparkConf;

sparkConf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("Source Cassandra to Target Cassandra job");
sparkConf.setMaster(jobConfig.getString("spark.context-settings.master")); // Leave empty if you are running on local spark cluster
sparkConf
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", sourceHost)
        .set("spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows", jobConfig.getString("spark.context-settings.fetchsize"))
        .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb", jobConfig.getString("spark.context-settings.splitsize"))
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", sourceUsername)
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", sourcePassword)
        .set("cassandra.username", sourceUsername)
        .set("cassandra.password", sourcePassword)
        .set("spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level", jobConfig.getString("spark.context-settings.spark.cassandra.consistency.level"))
        .set("spark.executor.memory", jobConfig.getString("spark.context-settings.spark.executor.memory"))
        .set("spark.driver.memory",jobConfig.getString("spark.context-settings.spark.driver.memory"))
        .set("spark.executor.tasks", jobConfig.getString("spark.context-settings.spark.executor.tasks"))
        .set("spark.mesos.coarse", "true")
        .set("spark.cores.max", jobConfig.getString("spark.context-settings.spark.cores.max"))
        .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
        .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
        sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Integer>> tupleRows = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sc.sc()).
cassandraTable(sourceKeyspace, sourceColumnFamily).select(sourceColumns)
.map(row -> {
    String authorName = row.getString("author_name");
    Integer numBooks = row.getString("num_books");
    return new Tuple2<>(authorName, numBooks);
})
```

Major Part by using com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector and writerBuilder:

```
CassandraConnector targetConnection = CassandraConnector.apply(
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host",targetHost)
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", targetUsername)
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", targetPassword)
    .set("cassandra.username", targetUsername)
    .set("cassandra.password", targetPassword)
);

CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(tupleRows).writerBuilder(targetKeyspace, targetColumnFamily, mapTupleToRow(String.class, Integer.class))
.withConnector(targetConnection)
.saveToCassandra();

sc.stop();
```

Viola! You are done!

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-340